# How to keep only distinct elements in Array while selecting and deselecting cells?

Tags: ios, swift, set

I have a collection view with different cells, and I want to be able to select multiple cells. I am able to do so, but when I click a cell that has already been selected, that same cell is again added to the array resulting in a repeat. What I want to happen is when it is clicked it will append the label to the array, and when it is clicked again it will delete it from the array. Below is what I have so far.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    arrayOfFriendsSelected.append(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item])
    print(arrayOfFriendsSelected)
    var cell = collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ShareCell
    cell.friendimage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    cell.friendimage.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("4F26D8").CGColor

    return true
}   

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    var cell = collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ShareCell
    arrayOfFriendsSelected.removeAtIndex(indexPath.item)
    print(arrayOfFriendsSelected)
    cell.friendimage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0

    return true
}
```

Comment: Use didSelect item delgate method only. before adding to array check object is der or not by using array contains method.If der remove else add.

Comment: Rather than using an array, use a set. Then you can quickly check if the friend is already in the set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a `Set` instead of `Array`.

Declare like

```
var setOfSelectedFriends = Set<String>()
```

and add

```
setOfSelectedFriends.insert(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item])
```

For removing, use

```
setOfSelectedFriends.remove(<elementToRemove>)
```

You can read more about Swift Sets [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID484).

Comment: How would I remove an object, like in the shouldDeselect function?

Comment: For some reason the shouldDeselect function is not being called. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Well you should be using didSelect functions instead of shouldSelect. Also, that can be a different question altogether.